# App Rejected but in app purchase is in review

Tags: ios, app-store, in-app-purchase

Our app has been rejected but in app is in review. Now we are ready to resubmit the binary, but we are unable to select the previously added in app purchase from the app summary page. The option to select in app purchase is unavailable. I cant even create a new in app and delete the previous one (because the previous one is In Review).

So my question is, whether the In APP purchase is already attached to the app or not, if i resubmit the binary, will the previously submitted In-APP gets reviewed and attached to the app or not.

Please advise.

Comment: You need not to do anything, just submit the app again. They are linked by the app identifier.

Comment: Your app status is `In-review`, Now you want to submit new binary. Am I right? you want to replace older one or submit new one(also want older which In-Review?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They are not attached although Apple guideline is that you submit you very first in-app purchase item with your app. All other in-app purchase items can be created and submitted independently.

If you resubmit your app and first in-app purchase item passes review you will be able to use it.